# A "for" loop with two variables, one increments every iteration and the increments every other iteration

Tags: c++

I can't seem to figure out a way to write a "for" loop that has two variables (`i` and `j`). I want `i` to increment by adding one every time, and `j` to increment by adding one every other time that `i` increments. Any ideas? (I've already tried a nested loop, or having them both initialized in the same condition statement.)

Comment: Why not just use `i / 2` instead of `j`?

Comment: The purpose of my question is to create a chart that shows all the numbers that have a "1" in the "4" binary spot between 5 and 36.

Comment: `for (int i = 5; i <= 36; ++i) { if (i & 4) printf("%d\n", i); }`

Answer (score 4):

Here goes a hacky way:

```
for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < N; j += i % 2, ++i) {}
```

This increments `j` at the end of every iteration where `i` had an odd value.

Comment: isn't there sequence point issues in the increment here with the comma operator?

Comment: No, the comma operator introduces sequencing.

Answer (score 0):

one way would be to do the following:

```
for(i=0, j=0; i<max; j += ((++i)&1) ){

}
```

here `j` will be incremented when `i` is even, if you want to increment `j` when `i` is odd then use the post increment